# How can we get all the date before 30 days in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following code as reference
and I am trying to get the details of 30 days before date list.
What should I replace?

```
   Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
       var dat = new Date(this.valueOf())
       dat.setDate(dat.getDate() + days);
       return dat;
   }

   function getDates(startDate, stopDate) {
      var dateArray = new Array();
      var currentDate = startDate;
      while (currentDate <= stopDate) {
        dateArray.push(currentDate)
        currentDate = currentDate.addDays(1);
      }
      return dateArray;
    }

var dateArray = getDates(new Date(), (new Date()).addDays(2));
for (i = 0; i < dateArray.length; i ++ ) {
    alert (dateArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more on _30 days before date list_

Comment: I'd like to suggest to play with MomentJS library http://momentjs.com/docs/

Comment: So you want an array with the Date-objects for the 30 last dates from today, counting backwards?

Comment: Before 30 days means from current date to previous date which is 30 days back.current date is 22-jully-2015 before 30 means 21-june-2015.I want to print all the date between these two date.

Comment: Yes exactly..@Esso55

Answer (score 0):

```js
Date.prototype.setDays = function(days) {
       var dat = new Date(this.valueOf())
       dat.setDate(dat.getDate() + days);
       return dat;
 }

   function getDates(startDate, counter) {
      var dateArray = new Array();
      var currentDate = startDate;
   //To get non-Zero Index to run the loop 
   var index=(counter > 0 ? counter : -counter);
      while (index > 0) {
        // Do not push the current date ::Optional dateArray.push(currentDate)
  //Will send days as +(after) and -(before)
        currentDate = currentDate.setDays(counter > 0 ? 1 : -1);
  
  //Push the date after the operation
  dateArray.push(currentDate);
  
  --index;
      }
      return dateArray;
    }

var dateArray = getDates(new Date(), 2);
$.each(dateArray||[],function(index,dateItem){
 console.log("Date "+ dateItem); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Here is the code you can try just send the difference.
Lets's say +30 days or -30 days.